# Youtube API: nolinkedyoutubeaccount error returned from api after disconnecting it from google plus identity

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, google-oauth

**Rephrasing of the question:**

Using the youtube api v 3.0 with oauth, when the user is sent to login, they have more than one option: e.g. the linked youtube account and the google account. The two different logins (access tokens) have different access to the api. I need the ability to just sent the user to log in to their proper youtube account (if they have one). How can my app do this? The user currently will have no idea which option they are supposed to choose, even if the app might be able to tell which they have chosen afterwards.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=1056190619576.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https:%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube

[image]

---

**original phrasing of the question:**

OK, this is getting really really confusing. My youtube account uses a gmail, so I think that it is safe to say that it is linked to my google account (if such a thing linkage does exist). A couple of days ago I was on youtube, and the web site roped me into giving my youtube account its own google+ account (as far as I could tell). My gmail/google account does not have google+. Anyway, shortly thereafter I undid the linking of a google+ account to the channel. Ominously, at this point youtube indicated that this was only temporary.

And the net effect of this is: I can't use the youtube api with the youtube account. It says nolinkedyoutubeaccount .

So, the youtube api seems unusuable to me. This confusion is enough to make a person's head spin. But can anyone suggest a solution to get my account working with the api again?

Edit: I have managed to reproduce the error (more or less) with a newly opened youtube account. More here:  https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4860

Comment: OK I have a bit of a work-around: When I go to the oauth2 login screen there are two "accounts" shown: the youtube account, and also gmail/google(?) account that the youtube account is linked to. Clicking on the youtube account basically stops the API calls from working as I have described in the question. So things seem pretty strange and wrong right now.

Comment: With these accounts, can you go here? You may need to re-link the channels: youtube.com/create_channel. Let us know if that doesn't work.

Comment: I can't go to that URL; it bounces me to the page of my youtube account  that I am logged into. So basically the API seems broken as far as I can tell. It lets the app user log in with youtube, sucessfully get a token, and then the api just returns errors when it is used by the app.

Comment: Bummer. Can you log the details here? https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label:APi-YouTube We track issues that way and will look into it. If this is affecting you, it's likely affecting other users as well.

Comment: I've just tried a few different flows to reproduce this without any luck. Can you open a bug with the exact steps you took? I feel like I am not following your steps exactly - how did you link Google+? Where did you go to unlink? Etc.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to this, I have submitted the issue (#4860).

Answer (score 1):

These blog posts should help explain what's going on

- http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api.html
- http://youtubecreator.blogspot.com/2013/04/using-google-page-identity-on-youtube.html

Based on what you describe, I think things are working as intended, but you do need to be careful to ensure that you select the correct channel when going through the OAuth 2 flow.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to do the reading, stop using apigee, and I'll make a login test .exe; then I'll see if I get it.

Comment: OK Jeff, version 2 of the youtube api seems to have what I am looking for. I read: "Rather than expose existing applications to accounts with potentially restricted functionality, we’re explicitly requiring that an application prepared to handle unlinked Google Accounts tells us so by using the API version 2.1, a new, minor version of the API. Our documentation explains that you can specify an API version by appending v=2.1 to the API request URI or by using the GData-Version: 2.1 request header. ". I am using version 3 and the google apis library for dot net. Can I achieve the same?

Comment: The other thing that I don't see mentioned, is that when the user is directed to the login screen, there is more than one "account" to log in to; the google account, the youtube account, and now even a google+ option as well. Can I scope this down to just a proper youtube channel (or have the user go an make one). https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=1056190619576.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https:%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube

Comment: v3 of the API uses a completely separate set of client libraries than v1/v2/v2.1. And you don't have any control over which items show up in the OAuth 2 channel picker, no. I believe that +Pages without channels might eventually disappear from that picker, but I don't know when that will be implemented on our end.

Comment: OK so it seems that authorized youtube api calls are not very practical at the moment, at least using oauth and v3. Is there a workaround that you can suggest to deal with this? I attached an image by the way, to make the question clearer.

Comment: I'm following up with the internal teams involved to make sure UX improvements are made to reflect the type of issue you're talking about. Thanks for going into details to explain.