# Only show YouTube channels with Oauth2 excluding Google+ Business page profiles not associated with a YouTube channel

Tags: youtube-api, oauth-2.0, google-plus

We have an application which shows the YouTube video performance statistics. We are using OAuth2 authentication to authenticate the YouTube account. The authorization page from the OAuth2 web-based "Select an account interface" shows YouTube Channel identities and also Google+ page identities. The Google+ page identities include those that are not associated with YouTube channel. This is confusing for the user as clicking on a Google+ page identity that does not have a YouTube channel results a failed attempt. We need to exclude the Google+ page identities that are not associated with a YouTube channel.

We have reviewed this post. http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/06/google-page-identities-and-youtube-api.html so understand the background.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube API: nolinkedyoutubeaccount error returned from api after disconnecting it from google plus identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428380/youtube-api-nolinkedyoutubeaccount-error-returned-from-api-after-disconnecting)